# Entity Framework Relationships Foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework-4.3

I have these classes and I'm using a Repository pattern and trying to get an IEnumerable to include the WorkOrderDetail. I'm new to MVC and Entity Framework and I can't figure out how to include the WorkOrderDetails.

```
public IEnumerable<Schedule> GetFuture()
        {
            string tZone = "Pacific Standard Time";

            DateTime today = Today(tZone);

            var schedule = context.Schedules
                .Where(s => s.Date >= today).ToList();            

            return schedule;
        }

public abstract class Entity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

 public class Schedule : Entity
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public bool Free { get; set; }

        public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }
        public virtual WorkOrder WorkOrder { get; set; }          
    }

 public class WorkOrder : Entity
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<WorkOrderDetail> WorkOrderDetails { get; set; }
     }
public class WorkOrderDetail : Entity
    {
       public string Job { get; set; }
       public bool Finished { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
var schedule = context.Schedules.Where(s => s.Date >= today).ToList();
```

to:

```
var schedule = context.Schedules.Include("WorkOrder.WorkOrderDetail").Where(s => s.Date >= today).ToList();
```

Comment: Or with ef 4.1 + you can use lambda syntax, `.Include(s=>s. WorkOrder.WorkOrderDetail)`

Comment: @LukeMcGregor  I tried with this but when I try to access Job in a view 'foreach (var detail in Model))
                {
                    @ detail.WorkOrder.WorkOrderDetail.Job                       
                }' It doesn't work.

Comment: @flean What happens when you try that, do you get an exception?  If so what is it?

Comment: @CodingGorilla  I figured it out, I only needed to use the selectmany on the model to access the details. I'm not sure if this is the best approach.  'foreach (var detail in Model
                        .Where(i => i.WorkOrderID ==            WorkOrderT.WorkOrderID)                                                          
                        .SelectMany(i => i.WorkOrder.WorkOrderDetails)                                    
                        )  {  @ detail.Job }'